# VsCode remove folder from compilation process

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

Is there any way to exclude or remove a folder from **compilation** process using VSCode and Java?

I have a root folder with some unused / deprecated folders which contains some errors. The problem is that every time I debug , compilation process display errors me about the problems on those old folders.

I tried with files.exclude parameter in workspace file with no success, those folder effectively are not displayed in root solution but they are still being taken for compilation process.

Many thanks,

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you should try to copy and paste the files you want to compile in a new folder and open that folder in VScode.

Whenever I try to open a new folder in VScode, then the files are compiled from that folder rather than the current folder.

Comment: Hi, What about git ?